# Swift Keyboard animation moving up and down

Tags: swift, animation, keyboard

When a text field is clicked, my app moves down into a white space and then back up with the keyboard. How do I get it to stop doing that? I just want to get the screen to move up a little when the keyboard is activated. 
This question is different than the other Swift keyboard questions because it uses the code from the book *I0S8 for programmers* from Deitel. And solving this problem might help others who own the book. 
Thanks,

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: "keyboardWillShow:",
        name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification,
        object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: "keyboardWillHide:",
        name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification,
        object: nil)        // listen for keyboard show/hide notifications
}
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self,
        name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self,
        name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)        // unregister for keyboard show/hide notifications
}
     // called when app receives UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let frame = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue!
    let size = frame.CGRectValue().size // keyboard's size

    // get duration of keyboard's slide-in animation
    let animationTime = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]!.doubleValue

    // scroll self.tableView so selected UITextField above keyboard
    UIView.animateWithDuration(animationTime) {
        var insets = self.tableView.contentInset
        insets.bottom = size.height
        self.tableView.contentInset = insets
        self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
    }
}    // called when app receives UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    var insets = self.tableView.contentInset
    insets.bottom = 2
    self.tableView.contentInset = insets
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
}
// hide keyboard if user touches Return key
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you adjust the `contentInset` property, you should also play around with the `contentOffset` property and adjust that to achieve the behavior you want. However I would recommend against using the insets and instead encourage you to take one of two roads:

1) If using Autolayout:

If you're using Autolayout and you hook up your constraint as an `IBOutlet`, on `willShow` adjust the constraint constant to whatever value you need.

```
self.constraint.constant = 2
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

which will adjust it with no animation and to animate:

```
self.constraint.constant = 2
UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

and then when `willHide` is called, just set the constraint constant back to 0 (or whatever it's default/original value was and animate).

2) If not using Autolayout:

Instead of adjusting constraints, adjust the frame position of the views you want to move and animate as necessary.

Comment: This helps a little, but I still have the scrolling problem. It no longer scrolls past the screen into whiteness, but it still scrolls all the way down to the bottom and then scrolls back to the top. Is there any way I can get it to just pop up the keyboard? Thanks again for your help so far.

Comment: I went back and changed the offset and the inset. That's what fixed it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry I never saw your first comment. Glad it worked out for you in the end though.

Comment: Helped me in fixing my issues.